# Replace all strings in a file with "SomeWord-####" with "SomeOtherWord-ABC"

Tags: vim, sed, grep

I have to replace thousands of occurrences of a String containing "SomeWord-" followed by four numbers (can be any four numbers).

for example, the file could contain:

```
blah:"someValue1",
otherThing:"someOtherValue1",
importantThing:"SomeWord-1232", 
etc:".....",
importantThing:"SomeWord-4567",
otherThing:"SomeWord-8438"
```

And it needs to become another string:

```
blah:"someValue1",
otherThing:"someOtherValue1",
importantThing:"SomeOtherWord-ABC", 
etc:".....",
importantThing:"SomeOtherWord-ABC",
otherThing:"SomeOtherWord-ABC"
```

What's the cleanest way to do this using sed, grep, vim etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim you can do

```
:%s/SomeWord-\d\+/SomeOtherWord-ABC/g
```

which matches 1 or more digits, if  you want exactly four then you can do

```
:%s/SomeWord-\d\{4}/SomeOtherWord-ABC/g
```